# How to change the css attribute of #header using jQuery and an array of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to edit a script that changes the images of a div as shown below, to change the background-image property of #header.

As you can see in my fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/HsKpq/460/ I am trying to show the `images into the $('#header').css('background-image',..................).fadeTo('slow',1);`

How can I do this? I guess I have to change some other parts too..

```
var img = 0;
var imgs = [
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9958532/2/istockphoto_9958532-sun-and-clouds.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/4629609/2/istockphoto_4629609-green-field.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9712604/2/istockphoto_9712604-spring-sunset.jpg'
];
// preload images
$.each(imgs,function(i,e){var i=new Image();i.src=e;});

// populate the image with first entry
$('img').attr('src',imgs[0]);


var opacity = 0.1; // change this for minimum opacity
function changeBg() {
    $('img').fadeTo('slow',opacity,function(){
        $('#header').css('background-image',..................).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}



setInterval(changeBg,5000);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HsKpq/460/ You have done 460 update already ??!!

Comment: @Amir It does not change the background-image property of the header, but the `<img>` in header. That means it changes all the images in the page. Not what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of fixes:

- Use a simple increment to keep track of the current image.
- typo: "images" -> "imgs"
- $("img") doesn't select anything, so the JQuery fadeto "complete" callback is never fired (I assume you meant to fade the div itself)
- you need "url('http://...')" for the ["background-image" CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

---

```
function changeBg() {
    if (i >= imgs.length) i=0;
    $('#header').fadeTo('slow',opacity,function(){
        var val = "url('" + imgs[i++] + "')";
        console.log(val);
        $('#header').css('background-image',val).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}
```

Here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHDs9/15/).

Comment: @Fataoulas that's a relatively easy fix, just reset i=0 once it exceeds the array length (link updated).

Comment: thank you very much, i have accepted your answer. for knowledge reasons, when the 3rd image changes back to 1st image, why there is this small duration of white background before the 1st image is shown?

Comment: @Fataoulas not sure I follow ...?  To me it looks like the same fade in/out each time.